# displaying value from jquery to html div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

well i know many of you would cast it as duplicate but i wanna justify that i have tried everything that i know but its not working, even seeing all answers from SO didnt rectified my problem.Coming to my question

here is my JQuery code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = show_cart_count();

function show_cart_count(){
    var get_count=2;
    alert(get_count);
    $("#show_count").val(get_count);
    //$("#show_count").innerHTML('get_count');
}
</script>
```

and here is my div tag

```
<div id="show_count" class="show_count" >0</div>
```

but despite my efforts the value of show_count doesn't get printed in div.

**EDIT-**

---

Just tried my code by placing div to another place and it was working.Any guesses about why its not showing on that particular position

```
<div class="check"> <a class="bag-icon" href="">Bag(<div id="show_count" class="show_count" >0</div>
            0)</a> </div>
```

This is its surrounding Code.. Any guesses whats wrong in here :)

Comment: `$("#show_count").text(get_count);` or  `$("#show_count").html(get_count);` for non Input elements

Comment: Did but didnt work mean tried them all but still nothing works

Comment: Since you use `window.onload` instead of `$(document).ready()` , keep it native JS and use `document.getElementById('show_count').innerHTML('get_count');`

Comment: `window.onload = show_cart_count();` is not what you want. EITHER `window.onload = show_cart_count;` OR since you have jQuery: `$(function() { show_cart_count(); });` plus use .html instead of .val

Comment: Thanks to all for replying :) Sometimes dumb things happen... Just changed Div id and booom it was working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) of `jQuery`.

and 2nd Use [document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
function show_cart_count(){
    var get_count=2;
    // alert(get_count);
    $("#show_count").text(get_count);
    //$("#show_count").html(get_count);
}



$(document).ready(function(){
     show_cart_count();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`div` elements don't have a `value` property, so you should use `text()` or `html()` to update their content:

```
$("#show_count").text(get_count);
```

If you want to set the `innerText` directly you can do either of the below:

```
$("#show_count")[0].innerText = get_count;
// or
$('#show_count').prop('innerText', get_count);
```

Answer (score 2):

For div elements you need to use the html() function instead of Val()

```
$("#show_count").html("new content");
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
    var get_count=2;
    alert(get_count);
    $("#show_count").html(get_count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_count" class="show_count" >0</div>
```

Comment: Tried this answer but doesn't work... I tried .html earlier also but its not showing. Even the alert is not popping up

Comment: Run the snippet. It works for me. Probably you are doing something wrong.

Comment: yeah i tried your snippet its working here but doesnt work in my project :(.  Dont know what the problem is

Comment: Tried all answer but couldn't run it

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery text function for non-input elements:

```
var get_count = 2;
$("#show_count").text(get_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually executing the function `show_cart_count()` and assigning what the function returns to window.onload

So `window.onload = show_cart_count();` should rather be `window.onload = show_cart_count;`

---

jQuery function `.val()` works for `TextArea`, `Input`, `Select` etc for others to change the innerText you use the fn `.text()` and to change the innerHTML you use fn `.html()`

So it will be `$("#show_count").text(get_count);` or `$("#show_count").html(get_count);` rather than `$("#show_count").val(get_count);`